Reset GitHub credentials
How can I reset my GitHub credentials on macOS to switch to a different account? Currently, when I push changes, Git automatically uses my existing GitHub account without prompting me to log in. I've deleted all Git-related entries in Keychain Access, but new entries are generated every time I push, and it still uses the old account. I want Git to prompt me to sign in again after pushing.
